# Data is not passing to the other page using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have been trying to use ajax in cart system the value is easily being added to cart in home page but when cart.blade.php page is opened the products are not displayed. I think data is being passed in  the cart.blade.php page.

**index.blade.php**

```
<div class="widget widget-control-header widget-shop-cart js-widget-shop-cart">
    <a class="control" href="{{route('cart.index')}}">
        <p class="counter">0</p>
        <span class="lnr lnr-cart" id="checkout">
        </span>

        <div class="wrapper-control-item item-add-cart js-action-add-cart">
            <a class="animate-icon-cart" href="#">
                <span class="lnr lnr-cart" >
                </span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the ajax code with all of its classes. 'js-action-add-cart' is used for calling the cart ajax.

**add-to-cart.js**

```
$(function() {
    var actionAddToCart = $('.js-action-add-cart');
    var cart            = $('.js-widget-shop-cart');
    var itemWishList    = $('.js-notify-add-wish-list');
    var items;

    var cartItems ={items:[]};

    actionAddToCart.each(function() {
        $(this).on('click', function(e) {
            var productid    = $(this).closest('.product').find('a').attr('id');
            var productName  = $(this).closest('.product').find('.product-name').text();
            var productPic   = $(this).closest('.product').find('img').attr('src');
            var productPrice = $(this).closest('.product').find('.price').text();

            if($(this).hasClass( "is-added" )){
                alreadyAddedToCart(productName);
            }else{
                $('#cartHover').append("<li style='width: 200px;border-bottom: 1px solid black;padding: 10px;padding-top:0px;position: relative'>\
                    <span style='width: 50px; position: relative'>"+productName+"</span>\
                    <span style='width: 30px; margin-left: 30px; position:relative'>PKR: "+productPrice+"</span>\
                    <i class='cancel glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle' style='right:5px; top:5px; position: absolute;float:right'></i>\
                    </li>");

                cartItems.items.push({id: productid, name: productName, pic: productPic , price :productPrice});
                items = JSON.stringify(cartItems);

                e.preventDefault();
                notifyAddToCart(productName);
                $(this).addClass('is-added');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    updateCart();
                }, 1000);
            }

        });
    });

    $('#checkout').click(function(){
        window.location.href = 'cartSession.blade.php?products='+items;
    });

    function updateCart() {
        //show counter if this is the first item added to the cart
        ( !cart.hasClass('items-added') ) && cart.addClass('items-added');
        var cartItems = cart.find('.counter'),
        text = parseInt(cartItems.text()) + 1;
        cartItems.text(text);
    };
});
```

**cartSessions.blade.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['products'] =$_GET['products'];
header('Location: shop-cart.blade.php');
exit();
```

Comment: Could you isolate your problem and reformulate it in more general terms?

Comment: Check updated question

Comment: Hi, this is Laravel Framework not Clear PHP :) you should use biuld in Session class 

@if(!Session::has("products"))  ....

and you have to pass data true ROUTE

Comment: example : `if(!Session::has("product")) {
 Request::session()->put("product", Request::segment(1) );
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really don't need to use `session_start()` in your blade template as Laravel handles starting your session via the middleware. You also want to serve your blade template via a route, not access them directly. Create a route that either has it's own closure or points to a controller method.

**Route with it's own closure**

```
// ------------------------------------------
// routes.php
// ------------------------------------------

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::get('/cart', function(Request $request)
{
    // Get the products from the request
    $products = $request->products;

    return view('shop-cart', ['products' => $products]);
});
```

**Route pointing to a controller**

```
// ------------------------------------------
// app/Http/routes.php
// ------------------------------------------

Route::get('/cart', [
    'as'   => 'cart', 
    'uses' => 'CartController@show'
]);


// ------------------------------------------
// app/Http/Controllers/CartController.php
// ------------------------------------------

<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class CartController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Show the cart.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show(Request $request)
    {
        // Get the products from the request
        $products = $request->products;

        return view('shop-cart', ['products' => $products]);
    }
}
```

Here we simply get the products from the request and pass them through as a variable called `$products` to the view. You would need to make the following change to your javascript:

```
$('#checkout').click(function(){
    window.location.href = '/cart?products='+items;
});
```